# Cross browser event handling and jquery support

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, jquery-events

Just read of ppk's web site that IE's mechanism of registering events does not set the `this` object to the actual element that was clicked. Instead it refers to the global window object. The [below](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) is quoted from his site:

> But when you use the Microsoft event
>   registration model the this keyword
>   doesn’t refer to the HTML element.
>   Combined with the lack of a
>   currentTarget–like property in the
>   Microsoft model, this means that if
>   you do
>
> ```
> element1.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)
> element2.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)
> ```
>
> you cannot know which HTML element
>   currently handles the event. This is
>   the most serious problem with the
>   Microsoft event registration model and
>   for me it’s reason enough never to use
>   it, not even in IE/Win only
>   applications.

jQuery handles this properly! I mean if we do something like:

```
$(element).click(function(){...});
```

`this` refers to the element in the question. How does jQuery handle this for IE browsers? What would be the equivalent js code for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `call` method, you can set the value of `this` in any function:

```
var element = document.getElementById('testy'),
    someFunction = function () {
        alert(this.id);
    };

someFunction.call(element); // alerts "testy"
```

This is how almost every library fixes IE's stupid "this" mistake: by adding a wrapper to the listener that you pass in, so that your listener is actually `called`.