# <a href="javascript:foo(this)"> passes Window, I want the tag element itself

Tags: javascript, html

I expect this to print "a" because when I call `foo(this)`, the argument seems to be the link tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo (e) {
        alert (e .tagName);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:foo(this)">click</a>
```

Instead, it prints "undefined". If I `alert(e)` it says "object Window". How do I make `foo` know which element launched it? Without passing/looking up ids.

Comment: what if you use `console.log(e.tagName);`

Comment: I think you need an `href` that is not the JavaScript function call. It should work if you use `href="#"` and you use `onclick="function...` for the script execution. I think it's something to do with how an anchor tag isn't a real tag without a proper `href`.

Comment: Don't use `e` for the obj. `e` is a standard for the event object

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should not use href for JavaScript. Bad practice, instead use onclick and `this` will magically point to the link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo(this)">click</a>
```

You also need to cancel the click action of the link. Either with return false or cancelling the event with preventDefault.

It is better to attach the event with [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: If we're going to be picky about coding philosophy I suppose it's worth pointing out that `href="javascript:void(0);"` is safer (no return false, no base url interference).

Comment: Also, `href="javascript:void(0);"` is better than `href="#"` because it doesn't make the browser viewport jump to the top of the document as soon as one clicks on the link.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this directly too

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this.tagName);">click</a>​
```

Comment: I don't want the tag name, that's just for demonstration purposes, I want the element.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` object is not handled the same in all browsers. This is one of the many items that libraries like Prototype and jQuery try to normalize. That said, however, most browsers will pass the appropriate `this` during on `onclick` handle (rather than the `href`) as many other answers have pointed out. If you want to handle the `this` appropriately, you'll need to do things like those detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5940964/422184).

Answer (score 0):

The others are correct in that it is indeed bad practice to put javascipt in an href property.

**However** we don't always have full control over the libraries we are obliged to maintain and use. Especially 3rd party tools.

The trick I use *when there is no other option left*, is to add a generated ID as a comment to the beginning of the HREF. Then use JQuery to search for anchor elements that have an HREF attribute starting with that ID.

This is very slow and inefficient but it *does* work.

```
<a href="javascript:/*YourIdGoesHere*/ foo($('a[href^=\'javascript:/*YourIdGoesHere*/\']')[0]); void(0);">click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo (a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo(this)">click</a>

function foo(obj) {
    alert(obj.tagName);
}​
```

Don't call the element `e` it's a standard for the event object.

[**JSfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLkMg/)